# Clear RecyclerView when enter is hit android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to have it so that when I hit enter the recyclerview is cleared out of the old data and new data is grabbed and put in and displayed. I have it so that anytime that enter is hit it grabs what is in the edittext and put that into a variable that is then searched for. The variable is being updated but the array that holds the searched for items isn't updated. Do I need to clear that array out? I think to do that I would need to use an ArrayList instead of a normal array. Would that be a better idea?

```
public View.OnKeyListener search = new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        searchItem = "";

        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            if(searchItem != searchBar.getText().toString())
            {
                searchItem = searchBar.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(imdb_activity.this, "The search is: " + searchItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Android view component", "Enter button was pressed and the value is: " + searchItem);
            }
            //clear recyclerview?



            goGetSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the updated list to the `recyclerview`, I assume that `goGetSearch` is the function where you pass the parameters to `recyclerview` and the `searchItem` is your list, so I hope you got the concept and if my assumption is wrong, you can edit it to fit in your case.

```
    public View.OnKeyListener search = new View.OnKeyListener()
     {
   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
     {
    searchItem = "";

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        if(searchItem != searchBar.getText().toString())
        {
            searchItem = searchBar.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(imdb_activity.this, "The search is: " + searchItem, 
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Android view component", "Enter button was pressed and the value 
          is: " + searchItem);
        }
        //clear recyclerview?



        goGetSearch(searchItem);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
   };
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, I was already using that variable but was grabbing it instead of passing it.goGetSearch takes the searched for term and goes to one api to get the IMDb id then uses that id to get the information on what was searched for. it is after all the information is grabbed that it goes to the recyclerview